# Issue with base64 encoding of data using HMAC

Tags: node.js

Using Nodejs, I'm attempting to generate a HMAC SHA256, base64-encoded signature of an XML message. I currently have the signature generation working using PHP.

The process seems fairly straightforward, and I'm able to generate base64-encoded value with Nodejs but, for some reason, the value does not match and is much shorter than what I get using PHP.

Below, I've included an example PHP script and result as well as the Nodejs implementation and result. With Nodejs, I'm using the native crypto module.

```
// PHP implementation

$xml = <<<EOD
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<dataset>
  <record>
    <id>1</id>
    <first_name>Carlos</first_name>
    <last_name>Ruiz</last_name>
    <email>cruiz0@engadget.com</email>
    <gender>Male</gender>
    <ip_address>156.225.191.154</ip_address>
  </record>
</dataset>
EOD;

$secret = 'secret';
$sig = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $xml, $secret));

echo $sig;
```

Result:
`ODhkYTc1YmQzNzc0NWUyNDJlNjY3YTY1NzZhYzFhZGYwOTJlMTIxODdjNzYxOWYyNGQxNGExOGVkYTIyZDQ0ZQ==`

```
// Nodejs implementation

var crypto = require('crypto');

fs.readFile('example.xml', 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
  function sig(str, key) {
    return crypto.createHmac('sha256', key)
      .update(str)
      .digest('base64');
  }
  console.log(sig(data, 'secret'));
});
```

Result:
`iNp1vTd0XiQuZnpldqwa3wkuEhh8dhnyTRShjtoi1E4=`

I've spent the day trying to figure this out and after a year+ of using Stack Overflow, this is my first question.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I notice in your first example your xml file is not a file, but a string. So.... what's the actual xml in `example.xml`? That said, a sha256 print is 256 bits, or 32 bytes, which base64 conversion makes about 4/3rd larger, so we should expect the base64 HMAC print to be around 42 character long. As such, the result from Node.js certainly *looks* the right length (43 characters with a padding `=` to align to 4 bytes), whereas the PHP string absolutely does not. It's *waaaaay* too long.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, from mscdex's answer I was able to figure out what I needed to do. As he explained, in my example, hash_hmac was returning a hex-encoded string which was then base64-encoded. Using that information I was able to get my nodejs code working by using 'hex' as the digest, converting to a string and encoding that string as base64.

Comment: as long as you are **extremely aware** that you are not generating base64 encoded HMAC values, but a twice-asciified string, which is an excellent sleeper bug in your software right there. Making the consuming code expect a base64-encoded true SHA-256 HMAC value is an infinitely better solution here.

Comment: The big picture of this post is: a PHP server (which I do not control) sends an XML POST with a header value that is equal to the base64-encoded HMAC value, using a shared key, and the body of the POST. I believe that, while taking into account what you have stated, all should be OK. Thanks again for your comments!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that PHP's `hash_hmac()` returns a hex-encoded string by default (see the `$raw_output` parameter [here](http://php.net/hash_hmac)), so you are base64-encoding a hex string instead of the actual of the raw, binary result.

So change this:

```php
$sig = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $xml, $secret));
```

to:

```
$sig = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $xml, $secret, true));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I had my mind so set on thinking PHP was functioning in a certain/expected way that I didn't think to look further into that side of things.

From your answer, I was able to get the required result by using 'hex' as the digest, converting to a string and base64-encoding that.